# Spring 3 Security j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

I'm trying to learn, how spring security works, so I've downloaded some sample project and then I tried to implement that solution to my project. But when I try to login, I get `404` error and in an address bar I have `http://localhost:8080/fit/j_spring_security_check`. I tried to look at similar questions here, but I wasn't able to realize, how to apply it to my project. I'd be really thankful, if somebody, who is more experienced, could help me.

My app structure looks like this:

[image]

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="cz.cvut.fit"/>

<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-security.xml"/>

</beans>
```

applicationContext-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="cz.cvut.fit" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled"
                                 proxy-target-class="true"/>
</beans>
```

applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/views/login.jsp*" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/views/denied.jsp" security="none"/>

<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied.jsp" servlet-api-provision="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/views/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/views/edit/**" access="ROLE_EDIT"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/views/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/views/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp"
                         default-target-url="/home.jsp"/>
    <security:logout/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="adam" password="adampassword" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            <security:user name="jane" password="janepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <security:user name="sue" password="suepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDIT"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Comment: `j_spring_security_check` is a Servlet where the actual authentication is made and you must map the action of your login form to this Servlet. Are you doing this on your login page - `<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="j_spring_security_check">...</form>`?

Comment: Please show your web.xml. /j_spring_security_check URL must be processed by springSecurityFilterChain filter.

Comment: Yes, I am... But I've got no clue, what to do next, to make it work well. :-/

Comment: I assume, that this part of web.xml will be enough: `<!-- START: Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- END: Spring Security -->`

Comment: this is my login form: `<form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label><input id="username" name="j_username"></br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label><input id="password" name="j_password" type='password'></br>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>`

Comment: Are you sure that `/home.jsp` isn't doing 404? Shouldn't it be `/views/home.jsp`? If it's not a case, add [`<security:debug>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-debug) to your config, try again and post output here.

Comment: I've solved it already...particulary....If I put JSP pages to `/` instead of `/WEB-INF/views`, then it works...however I want to use MVC as well, so I need to find out, how to do that :-/

Comment: Refer this question
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321169/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-pms-j-spring-security-check-in-dis/35585241#35585241>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to validate to a uri based on the current context path of the web page. the JSTL tag lib can be used to ensure you easily generate the correct urls based on the context of the application. You can do this by using a tag library if you want to get it implemented quickly. To do this you can add the jstl tag library to the top of the jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Then you can use the following to post to the login servlet.

```
<form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post" role="form">
```

This ensures you alway post to <your_application_context>/j_spring_security_check.

reference for jstl:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Add your web.xml File .Its Create Bean of Your springSecurityFilterChain .Then you Got Response

Answer (score 0):

The path `/j_spring_security_check` has changed to `/login` in spring 4 and it is handled in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

You can find it's source here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java