# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/pms/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have developed a Spring application and I implement Spring security integration to Login and Logout function in it. I used Spring security with xml configuration. But when I login to system it shows 404 for me. Console telling me, **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/pms/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'**

But I can not understand the error. What I have missed?

My **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printWelcome() {
                ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
                modelAndView.addObject("message", "Spring security allows you");
                modelAndView.setViewName("loginForm");
                return modelAndView;
    }
```

My **spring-security.xml** :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

      <http auto-config="true">
                        <intercept-url pattern="/loginForm"/>
                        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />
                        <form-login login-page="/loginForm" 
                          default-target-url="/login" always-use-default-target="true"  
                          authentication-failure-url="/loginForm?login_error=1" />
                        <logout logout-success-url="/loginForm" />
            </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="a2ztechguide" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And  of my Login page :

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
                    <font color="red"> Invalid user name or password, try again.
                        <br /> <br />
                    </font>
                </c:if>
                <form name="login_form"
                    action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
                    <div>
                        <table width="40%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" width="40%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">Custom Login Form
                                                <hr width="100%" size="1" noshade align="left">
                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="80">Username</td>
                                            <td valign="top" align="left"><input type='text'
                                                id='username' size="30" maxlength="40" name='j_username'
                                                value='<c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
                                                     <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}"/>
                                                   </c:if>' />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="80">Password</td>
                                            <td valign="top" align="left"><input type='password'
                                                name='j_password' size="30" maxlength="30"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Spring MVC respond with a 404 and report "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[...\] in DispatcherServlet"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577234/why-does-spring-mvc-respond-with-a-404-and-report-no-mapping-found-for-http-req)

Answer (score 14):

I finally solved this by modifying the line where I was declaring my custom login form page.

Added processing-url="/j_spring_security_check":

```
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
```

to my security-context.xml page

Comment: Nice man, Kudos. This must have been changed since some version of spring security.

Answer (score 1):

Below code solved my problem for annotation based security configuration.
http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")...other settings

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your servlet mappings in your web xml to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```